# Explain that there is exactly one point on the map that is vertically above the point it depicts

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

You are standing with a map in your hand inside the area depicted on the map. Explain that there is exactly one point on the map that is vertically above the point it depicts.

[image]

I am familiar with Banach's Fixed Point Theorem or Contraction Mapping Theorem. But I dont know how solve this problem. How do I show that there is such point? Other than to draw

Comment: If you are familiar with Banach's fixed point theorem, then what requirements must be met in order to being able to apply it? And concerning these requirements, how do they coincide with your map-problem? I like the drawing btw

Comment: Well, I have to assume map(metric space) is complete, and $f: X \rightarrow X$ is a contraction

Comment: $X$ is not your map. The area depicted is $X$. Imagine you spread the map on the ground. Then the domain of $X$ (i.e. the part of the ground) that is covered by the map is your $f(X) \subset X$, where each point of $X$ is mapped to the point on the ground directly beneath the corresponding point on the map. Is this a contraction?

Comment: Furthermore, think about:

- What is your metric?  
- Will the area be a complete space? And if yes, why?

Comment: Yes, I think im getting it, since map in my hand is kind of a contraction, unless it was 1:1 map. Then would just be a picture of a the ground. The area is a complete space, since well there is no ""gaps" just like the real numbers $R$ on x-axis or the whole $R^2$. Maybe I dont get it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $X\subset {\mathbb R}^2$ the area that is depicted by the topographic "map" $R$. This "map" itself is a rectangle  that is "laid over" a part of  $X$. We then have two mathematical maps, namely (i) the cartographic map (realized by the cartographers and the printer)
$$\phi_1: \quad X\to R\ ,$$ which is a contraction by a factor ${1\over 1000}$, say, and (ii) the projection $$\phi_2:\quad R\to X$$ of $R$ to the ground on which we have laid the "map" $R$. Given a point $p\in R$ the image point $\phi_2(p)$ can be physically determined by punching a needle at $p$ through the paper down to $X$. It follows that $\phi_2$ is an isometry.

The composition
$$f:\quad X\to X, \qquad x\mapsto \phi_2\bigl(\phi_1(x)\bigr)$$
is a contraction of the complete metric space $X$ with Lipschitz constant ${1\over1000}$. By Banach's fixed point theorem there is exactly one point $\xi\in X$ with $$\phi_2\bigl(\phi_1(\xi)\bigr)=f(\xi)=\xi\ .$$
But this is saying that punching a needle through the point $\phi_1(\xi)\in R$ hits exactly the point $\xi\in X$.

By the way: There is a (quite deformed) homunculus in your brain that is a mental picture of your bodily self. Exactly one spot of this homunculus depicts the very spot where it is located.